# Firefox titlebar doesn't follow gtk.css .titlebar:backdrop instruction

Tags: gnome, firefox, gtk

I'm using a pretty standard ubuntu. I wanted to have a way to easily see which window is active and found a way to change the color of the titlebar. I created a gtk.css file, that sets the .titlebar background as a color, and .titlebar:backdrop as another one. It works great, except for firefox, which will use the standard color and not the backdrop one, even if it isn't the active window.

Comment: I'm using a pretty standard ubuntu What the heck does this mean?

Comment: Yeah sorry, just meant I didn't modify anything else, install some theme or other gnome extension that could potentially change things up